# Why do the children nodes rerender when the parent node is not even being updated?

Tags: material-ui

I run into a performance issue for a chat app.  Imagine I need to render a list of chatrooms in `ChatList`.

If both `ChatList` and `ChatListItem` are already `PureComponent`, and they already show as gray, why do the children of ChatListItem still rerender and take 245ms?

In my mind I always thought if a list is pure and unchanged, then it shouldn't even re-render items (children)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which kind of components the `ChatListItem` contains? If the components depend on a value stored inside a Provider like (Redux or Material UI) it's possible that thet bypass the `PureComponent` check.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant PureComponent check are always done as Redux data comes as prop there is no way for it to be by passed.
Without a significant code si difficult but there are cases (IE: routes with HoC in render props) that can make your component not only _update_ but even _remount_

Comment: Yes, this is true for the data that are passed up to bottom. But in case the components below are connected to the store they bypass the PureComponent check.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant nothing special in the `ChatListItem`, see updated screen cap

Comment: The `WithStyles` component is an HoC that connect the component to the Material-UI Provider. Are you using a theme with Material?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant I'm using `export default withStyles(styles)(ChatListItem)
` as documented in https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component for generating class names from `const styles`.  I'm using a theme arrow func for `styles`.  I do have a `MuiThemeProvider` providing a custom theme but it is only created once and not being updated.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you instantiate the `MuiThemeProvider`?

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong here but the issue might come from the HoC since it always re-render. You should probably investigate a bit more in that direction. Without any reproduction it's a bit hard to reproduce and understand the issue.

Comment: @Henry did you figure this out? Also running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10778#issuecomment-473526403

It's a Material-ui List performance issue